# C++ when using ofstream, cannot write to file created

Tags: c++

this code is supposed to read a file that is specified by the user (I used a 6 line .txt), grab a number of lines from the bottom of the original file and paste them into a new file.

The problem is I cannot seem to write into my archSal.txt. I have verified that the original file is read, archSal is created, the loop to write is entered successfully, and iCount and iIgnore are synced up. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void CopiaFichero (int iNum, int iCount, ifstream & archEntrada)
{
    ofstream archSalida("archSal.txt");
    string linea;
    int iIgnora = (iCount - iNum) +1;

    archEntrada.clear();
    archEntrada.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    iCount = 0;
    archSalida.open("archSal.txt");

    // write loop
    while (getline(archEntrada, linea))
    {
        if (iIgnora == iCount)
        {
            archSalida << linea << endl;
            iIgnora++;
        }
      iCount++;
    }
    archSalida.close();
}

int main()
{
    int iNum = 0, iCount = 0;
    bool hayLineas = false;
    string nomArch, linea;
    ifstream archEntrada(nomArch);

    cout << "Type in the name of the file" << endl;
    cin >> nomArch;
    cout << "Type in the number of lines to copy " << endl;
    cin >> iNum;

    archEntrada.open(nomArch);

    // verify that lines to copy is less than or equal to actual lines
    do
    {
        while(getline(archEntrada, linea))
        {
            ++iCount;
        }
        if (iCount >= iNum)
        {
            hayLineas = true;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "A copy cannot be made" << endl;
            cout << "Type in the number of lines to copy " << endl;
            cin >> iNum;
        }

    }while (hayLineas != true);

    // Call function with data
    CopiaFichero(iNum, iCount, archEntrada);

    archEntrada.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The first 5 lines of `CopiaFichero ` are completely pointless, and should be removed. Also, whenever you open a file you should immediately test if the open succeeded (for example, by using `is_open()` and report an error if it didn't.

Comment: The shown code erroneously attempts to open the output file twice, same error as the duplicate question. An unrelated bug is that `main()` attempts to open a file for input with an empty filename. It looks like you do not fully understand how file streams work, and you should reread the relevant chapters in your C++ book.